# Devexpress xtragrid filter by value

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

Hi all help please how to filter devexpress xtragrid so it doesn't show rows starting with `"!!!"` in column agent.
Thak you.

Comment: What is the source of the string "!!!"? Is it your data? What is your datasource?

Comment: It's a result of query from ms sql server 2005 database

Answer (score 1):

Just use [ColumnView.ActiveFilterString](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ActiveFilterStringtopic) property as follows:

```
gridControl.DataSource = new List<DataObj> { 
    new DataObj(){ Agent = "AMD" },
    new DataObj(){ Agent = "!!!AMD" },
};

((ColumnView)gridControl.MainView).ActiveFilterString = "[Agent] NOT LIKE '!!!%'";
```

or even

```
((ColumnView)gridControl1.MainView).ActiveFilterString = "Not StartsWith([Agent], '!!!')";
```

Related help article: [Filtering Overview](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument697)

Answer (score -1):

If the data is cumming from a SQL query, you could filter out rows having such data on the WHERE condition or in you code before binding to the datagrid. This is not a DevExpress issue.

Comment: my query returns for example 5 rows. column agent is IBM, Apple, Intel, !!!AMD, NVidia. I have a checkbox. if checkbox checked I show all agents. either I don't show row that contains !!!AMD in column agent. For filtering in a query I have to write two queries. It's not good idea.

Comment: Now if you still want to show AMD but not !!!AMD, you first need to realize that !!!AMD is probably bad data. In this case, you need to work on the result returned from your query and strip out the string '!!!' before binding to the GUI control. Better yet, fix the data on the database so that such characters are remeoved as they don't seem to make sense in general.

Comment: NO no no. We have two cases: 1. checkbox is checked: I show ALL rows. 2. Check box is unchecked I show all rows EXCEPT rows containing items in agentColumn starting with "!!!"

Comment: You can have 1 datatable with 2 views. 1 view for all the data and the 2nd view is a filtered view. You can do this on a datatable/dataset as in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk13kdh0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx or using the grid as in http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument2567/Filter_Expressions